# Dockerfile to install scikit-learn on rasp pi hardware

Tags: python, docker, numpy, scikit-learn, raspbian

How to make a Dockerfile for Raspbian hardware that can install scikit-learn? I haven't had any luck with debian-slim or Alpine Linux images.

```
# Use a base image for Raspberry Pi with Alpine Linux
FROM arm32v6/alpine:3.14

# Update package repositories and install necessary dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache update && \
    apk --no-cache add python3 python3-dev py3-pip build-base gcc gfortran wget freetype-dev libpng-dev openblas-dev && \
    ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

# Install scikit-learn and bacpypes3 using pip3
RUN pip3 install scikit-learn bacpypes3

# Clean up by removing unnecessary packages and cache
RUN apk del python3-dev py3-pip build-base gcc gfortran && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Start your application
CMD ["python3", "bacnet_server.py"]
```

Comment: Have you tried installing from apk? [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#alpine-linux), or `sudo apk add py3-scikit-learn`

Comment: can you do that in dockerfile?

Comment: @vahvero that worked great thanks for sharing post a answer and ill hit the green box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use APK to install `scikit-learn`

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#alpine-linux)

`apk add py3-scikit-learn`

Installs the python3 package.